# How to check whether ACTION_VIEW is done or not in Android PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-activity, android-popupwindow

Below is my code.

> I had gone through some links but not found the solution.I want to know whether user has completed the ACTION_VIEW or not or simply pressed the back button.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("url"));
                 mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Do you override onBackPressed in your Activity?

Comment: @SergeyNikitin i have override the onBackPressed and i have commented the super.onBackPressed(); . I don't want the user to exit the application on back press.